# Divert TCP connection

Tags: networking, tcp, routing, wireshark

I am trying to divert a TCP connection. Given a client (C) which is connected to a router R and two servers (S1 and S2) are connected to the router, C initially connects to S1. I am trying to write an iptables rule in the router to divert all traffic to S2. But the problem is, S2 keeps on sending RST messages and the connection is never established. I ran wireshark on all the boxes and noticed this: C sets up a TCP connection with S1 and when my iptable rule starts is active, it sends an ACK to S2 which sends back a RST and then they loop on this for time. Is there a way to divert TCP connections like this?

Comment: You want to divert a connection that is in progress? It's damn hard. Diverting a connection before it is established however is trivial.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for ways to divert while it is in progress.

Comment: This is almost impossible to do. TCP protocol has Sequence numbers that are generated randomly at the start of each connection and can not be re-used. The only way to "divert" it is to close the connection and force client to re-connect.

Comment: But what is the motive of doing all this. May I know what u are tying to do ..